# Weblogic memory-based session persistence

Tags: session, weblogic, persistence

Memory-based session persistence doesn't seem to work in Weblogic (12c).

**Please note:** I am running a local basic single-server (no cluster) setup.

If I add the following snippet to my weblogic.xml:

```
<session-descriptor> 
    <persistent-store-type>memory</persistent-store-type> 
</session-descriptor>
```

Upon redeploying the session beans don't persist. In particular I have a Spring MVC app, and the Spring form bean is gone, since taking any action on the page results in the following error:

```
####<Sep 8, 2017 1:28:38 PM MDT> <Error> <HTTP> <D-864597> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <bdf6551d-4eb8-454d-aa08-6f5f7c424785-0000012d> <1504898918422> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-101017> < 
. 
. 
. 
 Root cause of ServletException. 
org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Expected session attribute '<name_of_spring_form_bean>'
```

Interestingly however, file-based session persistence seems to work, since if I add the following snippet in my weblogic.xml

```
<session-descriptor> 
    <persistent-store-type>file</persistent-store-type> 
</session-descriptor>
```

it works as expected.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The "memory" value for the tag persistent-store-type means "no session replication". The good value is "replicated" if you want the session to be persisted across the clustered servers.

Comment: I didn't mention it in the original question, but will update it now.  I am just running a basic local single-server (no cluster) setup, so in my case "replicated" would not apply.